# I'm using the https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_callkit_incoming. Nothing happens when I use the start call function. Is it something I'm doing wrong?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have never used flutter_callkit_incoming dependency before and I seem to have problems.
Can I get help from anyone
This is the code that calls
I want to link it with fcm.[image: My fcm code]
[image: Code to make a call]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a seState({}); inside your function.

Comment: I'm confused here. Which function should I  add it to

Comment: On the function that you're trying to get to do something. `void startCall(){//all your code here - at the end setState({})}`

Comment: It's in a stateless widget

Comment: Try making it statefull widget. Erase the stateless and make it statefull

Comment: It didn't work. Have you tried it before?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).